# Dynamic table name doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an existing multiple database with each database préfixed by customer name and table also. Like
cust1.cust1_mytable

I use loadmetadata évent of doctrine but in production it doesn't work cause it's cached.

Do you have any solution ? Generate multiple metadata, one for each customer but how ? And how to use it ?

Thanks

Comment: If each client is dynamic, maybe you can use (not recommended) a ephimeral cache as in development mode. Put `metadata_cache_driver: array` and `query_cache_driver: array` in your doctrine production configuration.

Comment: I don't understand the need of prefixing the table name.

Comment: It's historical, i Can Ask you too :)